# General Tree in Haskell = Rose Tree? Postoder for a rose tree?

Tags: haskell, tree, postorder

I was supposed to create a data structure for a Tree, where every Node has an undefined amount of branches. I am guessing this will be a rose tree.

```
data GTree a = Node a [GTree a]
```

Now I am supposed to write a postorderG function that will give me a list of all my elements in my general in a postorder sequence
I wrote this but it does not seem right... Could someone help me?

```
postorderG :: GTree a -> [a]
postorderG (Node x l r) = postorder l ++ postorder r ++ [GTree x]
```

Comment: The `Node` constructor only has two arguments so your destructuring will look like `postorderG (Node x children)`. I suggest you look at `concatMap` and note that `postorderG` has the required type for the first argument.

Answer (score 0):

`GTree` is a *type* constructor, not a data constructor; a tree would be created with `Node x []`, not `GTree x`.

*However*, you don't need to create a tree at all here. You just need a the *value* stored at the root of the input tree for the final list in the return value.

```
postorderG :: GTree a -> [a]
postorderG (Node x ch) =  concatMap postorderG ch -- [a]
                          ++ [x]         -- [a], not [GTree a]
```

If you wanted to, you could create a singleton tree to append to `ch`, the apply `postOrderG` to each child and the new singleton in order.

```
postorderG (Node x ch) = concatMap postorderG (ch ++ [Node x []])
```

Taking advantage of the `[]` monad instead of using `concatMap`, the RHS would look like either

```
(ch >>= postorderG) ++ [x]
```

or

```
(ch ++ [Node x []]) >>= postorderG
```